# Is "yet again" negative in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Usually from what I learned, "yet" is used as a negation in the sentence, like "...have not...yet".

However, if the sentence is "**He failed the test yet again**". Here, is the "yet again" positive or negative?

If we add a tag question to this sentence, should it be "did he?" or "didn't he?"?

Comment: ***yet*** is effectively just an "intensifier" in your cited context, where it's only really "negative" because it's emphasising the already negative term ***failed** [again]*.

Answer (score 2):

*yet* is not necessarily negative.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yet)
> Yet: adverb
> Still; until the present time

Hence we have an example such as *I have not yet finished this answer* or its equivalent *I have yet to finish it*. The second version demonstrates that *yet* is a temporal modifier that implies no negation.

*He failed yet again* is a little more complex. *Yet* is used more in the manner of *still*. It refers the reader to the time he failed the test, emphasising that, until that time (rather than the present time of reading) he had previously failed it. He was still in the state of having failed.

*Yet* implies no negation in this construction. Consider the parallel “He won the trophy yet again”. *Yet* is acting as an emphatic temporal marker rather than a marker of positivity or negativity.

Comment: The tag question would be "didn't he", as in "He did it, didn't he?"

Comment: @Peter helpful. I restricted my answer to the principal usage question only.

Comment: Other than these rare and somewhat archaic positive constructions, _yet_ is an NPI, and only occurs in negative contexts.

Comment: @Peter: The tag question can actually be either positive or negative—negative if you wish to emphasize the action taken, positive if you wish to emphasize the action the speaker is going to take going forward: "He failed the test yet again, did he? Well, we'll see how he likes being grounded for three weeks." In the latter, it amounts to something like "Did I hear that right?"